# Widget with width and offset relative to parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to render something that looks a bit like a scrollbar to indicate that I am on page 2/5. To do this, I would need a widget with the following:

- The width is 20% width relative to the size of the parent
- Top-left of the widget is offset by 40% relative to the size of the parent

I was able to accomplish the first point using a FractionallySizedBox but I'm not sure how to compose this to accomplish the offset. Thanks!

Here is a Flutter codepen illustrating what I have so far. I would like to offset this by 40% relative to the parent while still preserving the 20% width.

https://codepen.io/venkatd-the-bashful/pen/jOWYQXz

Snippet of the example below

```
class PagePositionDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          width: 300,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              heightFactor: 1,
              widthFactor: 0.2,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Layout Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) with some row:

```dart
class PagePositionDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          width: 300,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
              return Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    // your offset percentage * total width
                    width: (2 / 5) * constraints.maxWidth,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    // your 'scrollbar' percentage * total width
                    width: (1 / 5) * constraints.maxWidth,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. With this constraints.maxWidth I successfully put two AutoSizeText in a Row, each maxWidth 50%.